# Sveltekit nodejs build not running in cpanel on shared hosting

Tags: node.js, cpanel, svelte, sveltekit

I have built a sveltekit app using `adapter-node`, copied the files from the build folder to a folder in my cpanel account. I setup a node app and selected the folder as the root folder and `index.js` as the startup[image: As shown here]

I am getting a 503 error when I visit the domain[image: 503 error]

but the app runs on local host with `node build index.js`

Comment: There is no node.js error logs in the question, so it is impossible to tell why it fails. I suggest you contact your CPanel provider support.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this?

Comment: No i switched to python, will try it again on another cpanel account